# What's the real limit for NUMBER data type in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, precision, numeric

I need help with understanding NUMBER data type, because 2 below statements from [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-9401BC04-81C4-4CD5-99E7-C5E25C83F608) seems to be for me mutually exclusive.

"The NUMBER data type stores zero as well as positive and negative fixed numbers with absolute values **from 1.0 x 10^-130 to but not including 1.0 x 10^126.**"

"**The precision p can range from 1 to 38**. The scale s can range from -84 to 127."

My questions:

1. How it's possible to handle such big value like 1.0 x 10^126 with precision(number of all digits in a given numeric value) equal 38. As far as I understand the value 1.0 x 10^126 require precision at least 126, because the value need 126 digits to be stored.
2. How it's possible to have precision like 38 and scale bigger than that, ex. 127?

Sorry in advance, if the question seems to be obvious for everybody other than me.

Comment: Oracle reserves 1 byte for exponent (scale), one byte for sign and part of the low values and up to 20 bytes for precision, where each byte hold numbers from 0 to 99. In your example Oracle will consume only two bytes for 10^x: one for exponent and one for the value itself (that falls in range 1-100). See https://dbfiddle.uk/LY37_fPM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How it's possible to handle such big value like 1.0 x 10^126 with precision(number of all digits in a given numeric value) equal 38. As far as I understand the value 1.0 x 10^126 require precision at least 126, because the value need 126 digits to be stored.

Oracle reserves 1 byte for the scale and then stores 2-digits per byte for the precision so if you have a scale of 127 and a precision of 38 then the value stored could be:

```
99999999999999999999999999999999999999000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

*(thirty-eight 9-digits followed by eighty-nine 0-digits)*

Any of the `0` digits will not be stored in the database and only the `9` digits would be stored.

Therefore you cannot store a 127-digit number, you can only store the first 38 significant digits of the 127-digit number.

Storing `1e125` is simple, the scale byte would encode the value `125` and then the data would be a single byte encoding the value `1` (Oracle uses a proprietary format so the byte values are not `125` and `1` but you should be able to understand the concept; if you want to see the exact binary values then use the `DUMP` function).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fXX_Q998)

> How it's possible to have precision like 38 and scale bigger than that, ex. 127?

Don't store a number, store a string or store a binary value.

If you are expecting to store it as a numeric data type then you cannot because the limitations of the data-type prevent it.

Comment: Alternative to string and binary may be User-Defined type that implements arithmetic operations (like `BigDecimal` in Java, for example).

Comment: @astentx You could use a user-defined type to convert a string or binary values stored in the database to a Java `BigDecimal` and then wrap the methods of the `BigDecimal` into methods of the user-defined type allowing you to perform arithmetic operations and then convert it back to a string or binary value to store in the database but I don't know of any way to store a Java `BigDecimal` directly in a column (without converting it to an intermediate format, such as string or binary). If there is a way then you should create an answer with an example as it would be interesting to see.

Comment: I was about creating UDT wrapper or implementing your own algorithms and declaring column type as UDT: `create table tab(col udt_name)`. Of course without direct storage of Java objects, Java BigDecimal was just an example of how arbitrary-length numbers may be handled.